# Mobile Responsiveness - Portfolio Custom Grid

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

I'm attempting to have my portfolio grid show in 2 columns on mobile, but still fit inside the one "full page row" such as it is on desktop

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.vc_basic_grid .vc_grid.vc_row .vc_grid-item.vc_visible-item, .vc_media_grid .vc_grid.vc_row 
.vc_grid-item.vc_visible-item {
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: 50%;
}
```

On some mobiles the grid goes into 2 columns but is squashed to the left side of the screen - and only using up half the screen for the two columns. On other devices, the portfolio grid blocks are so tiny you cannot even see the featured image.

[Companies Slide - View Portfolio Grid](https://neue2.run-time.co.za/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You can use the `display: flex` property, you just need to give `display: flex` to the parent and remove `display:inline-block` from the child

```
.vc_grid.vc_row.vc_grid-gutter-30px .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}   
.vc_basic_grid .vc_grid.vc_row .vc_grid-item.vc_visible-item, .vc_media_grid .vc_grid.vc_row .vc_grid-item.vc_visible-item {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: that did the trick thank you !I made it 25% for 4 columns which is now letting it fit in the "one page view". How do I prevent this from affecting the "Team" grid in the previous slide. It is showing the team grid items also at 25%.